# How do I make my custom element update based on the object that created it

Tags: javascript, html

I have an object from class:

```
class House {
    constructor(user, name, cost, level) {
        this.user = user;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.level = level;
    }

    get costValue() {
        return this.cost;
    }
    get levelValue() {
        return this.level;
    }

    setLevel = (newLevel) => {
        this.level = newLevel;
    }

    setCost = (newCost) => {
        this.cost = newCost;
    }

    levelUp = () => {
        if (this.user.materials >= this.cost) {
            this.user.subtractMaterials(this.cost);
            this.setLevel(this.level + 1);
            this.setCost(this.cost * 1.25);
        }
    }

    canLevelUp = () => {
        return this.user.materials >= this.cost;
    }
}
```

And the HTML object

```
const houseComponent = (houseObj) => {
    const house = document.createElement('div');
    house.className = 'house';

    const title = document.createElement('h2');
    title.innerHTML = houseObj.name;

    const level = document.createElement('p');
    level.innerHTML = `Level: ${houseObj.levelValue}`;

    const cost = document.createElement('p');
    cost.innerHTML = `Cost: ${houseObj.costValue}`;

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'Level Up';
    button.onclick = function() {
        if (houseObj.canLevelUp()) {
            houseObj.levelUp()
        }
    };

    house.appendChild(title);
    house.appendChild(level);
    house.appendChild(cost);
    house.appendChild(button);
    return house;
}
```

The HTML renders fine, but when the button is clicked the HTML won't update.
If I console log the house and the `User`, their values update correctly just won't update.

How do I make the HTML element reactive to the objects that it uses to render it?

Only vanilla js, no frameworks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you expect to or want to update the DOM nodes showing the values?

Comment: Yes so for example i would like `cost.innerHTML = 'Cost: ${houseObj.costValue}';` to update when the `houseObj.costValue` updates

Comment: You would need to have the setter for e.g. cost update the relevant DOM node or implement some kind of observer pattern.

Comment: so something along the lines of, when the value updated "re-get" the element with the value and update it manually? There's no way to make this do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is no listener to update `level` tag (I mean the `p` tag that shows `level` value) to update `innerHTML` of the tag when `levelUp();` methods called.

You've just changed the level of `houseObj` so you need to change the `p` tag when the `levelUp();` method is called, like this:

```
 button.onclick = function() {
      if (houseObj.canLevelUp()) {
          houseObj.levelUp();
          level.innerHTML  =  `Level: ${houseObj.levelValue}`;
      }
  };
```

```js
class House {
  constructor(user,name,cost,level) {
      this.user = user;
      this.name = name;
      this.cost = cost;
      this.level = level;
  }

  get costValue() {
      return this.cost;
  }
  get levelValue() {
      return this.level;
  }

  setLevel = (newLevel) => {
      this.level = newLevel;
  }

  setCost = (newCost) => {
      this.cost = newCost;
  }

  levelUp = () => {
      if (this.user.materials >= this.cost) {
          //this.user.subtractMaterials(this.cost);
          this.setLevel(this.level + 1);
          this.setCost(this.cost * 1.25);
      }
  }

  canLevelUp = () => {
      return this.user.materials >= this.cost;
  }
}


const houseComponent = (houseObj) => {
  const house = document.createElement('div');
  house.className = 'house';

  const title = document.createElement('h2');
  title.innerHTML = houseObj.name;

  const level = document.createElement('p');
  level.innerHTML = `Level: ${houseObj.levelValue}`;

  const cost = document.createElement('p');
  cost.innerHTML = `Cost: ${houseObj.costValue}`;

  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'Level Up';
  button.onclick = function() {
      if (houseObj.canLevelUp()) {
          houseObj.levelUp();
          level.innerHTML  =  `Level: ${houseObj.levelValue}`;
      }
  };

  house.appendChild(title);
  house.appendChild(level);
  house.appendChild(cost);
  house.appendChild(button);
  return house;
}

var f = houseComponent(new House({materials:50},"name",10,1))
document.body.append(f);
```